# What's the difference between these two sentences below?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

> 1. "Your opinion is quite different from that of the authorities."
> 2. "Your opinion is quite different from it of the authorities."

Comment: To start, your second sentence is very awkward at best. (I'm not convinced it's technically ungrammatical, but it's certainly very close to being so from a pragmatic point of view. I'm comparing it to *It was she of the Valkyries*, which has the same construction and *sounds* better, if still being a bit odd.)

Answer (score 1):

The second one isn't good, but the first is okay. Possibly:

> Your opinion is quite different than that of the authorities